# Implicit Matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, implicit

I have matrices in a multiplication and they are 2x2, 2x1 and 2x1.

```
[ a b        [ e(A1)          [ A1
  c d ]  X     f(A2) ]    =     A2 ]
```

How can I calculate A1 and A2 in Python ? I think I will use implicit methods but how ?

Comment: Is your question about the mathematics of finding `A1` and `A2` in your problem, or one of how to program it? I'm not sure this is the right site for the former sort of question. Maybe check out [the Math Stack Exchange site](http://math.stackexchange.com) (be sure to read their FAQs before asking a question there). If this really is a programming question, you'll need to provide a bunch more detail, like how you're defining your matrices.

Comment: Yes I need to find these A1 and A2 values by using Python. But I don't know how to code it. In fact my problem is complex  but I simplified it in order to get a universal solution on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Installing numpy in Linux is such easy as:

```
 $ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.3MB 92kB/s
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.11.2
```

Do it as `root` if you are not in `virtualenv`.

There is an example of matrices multiplication in the interactive Python session below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> np.matmul(a, b)
array([[4, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Numpy is the best choice if you have to play with mathematics.

Comment: But my question is implicit as you can see e(A1) and f(A2). I mean I have A1 but at the same time I want to find it. So I can not simply code A1 = blabla.. Because I don't know it.

Comment: so isn't it a problem of transforming an equation?

Comment: Yes I think so. Actually problem is in much more complex form. I simplified it for Stack oveflow.